# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<graphql endpoint>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: python, ssl, https, graphql, ssl-certificate

I am trying to create a graphql client using `python_graphql_client` package.
My graphQL endpoint is an https link.

But when i try to run a query, I get this error:

`exc: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='<graphql endpoint>', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /graphql (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1131)')))`

Here is my code snippet:

```
def Init( self,  GRAPHQL_SERVER_ENDPOINT):
        rv = False
        error = ""
        # Instantiate the client with an endpoint.
        try:
            header = { f"{self.xAPIKeyName}" : f"{self.xAPIKey}" }
            self.gqlClient = GraphqlClient(endpoint=GRAPHQL_SERVER_ENDPOINT, verify=False, headers=header) #os.environ["SETI_GRAPHQL_SERVER_ENDPOINT"])
            if(self.gqlClient != None):
                rv = True
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical("EXCEPTION connecting to GraphQL endpoint="+os.environ["GRAPHQL_SERVER_ENDPOINT"]+"; exc: "+str(e))
            error="EXCEPTION connecting to GraphQL endpoint="+os.environ["GRAPHQL_SERVER_ENDPOINT"]+"; exc: "+str(e)
        if( rv==False ):
            self.Trace("eq_stats.Init() FAILED: "+error)
        return rv


def ExecuteQuery( self, query):
        rv = None
        error = "UNKNOWN"

        try:
            response = self.gqlClient.execute(query=query)
            rv = response["data"]
            error = ""
        except Exception as e:
            logger.critical(f"ExecuteQuery EXCEPTION, query: {query}, exc: {str(e)}")
            error=f"ExecuteQuery EXCEPTION, query: {query}, exc: {str(e)}"

        if( rv==None ):
            error=f"ExecuteQuery ERROR, query: {query}, exc: {error}"
            self.Trace(error)
        return rv, error

.....
.....

eqti, err = eqs.ExecuteQuery( equipmentTypeInfoQuery % (swArchitecture) )
        if (err!=""):
            logger.critical(f"EquipmentTypeInfo Query FAILED: {err}")
```

For now I have just added `verify=False`. But I know it should not be done.

I have a certificate but not sure how to use it.

Need someone's help!!

Thanks in advance